# FastAPI dynamic multiple path parameters

Tags: python, url, fastapi, pydantic

I would like to achieve the following :

- My application contains some "sub-domains" which correspond to different parts of the app.
- Each domain has its own entities
- I would like to write a single controler like so :

```
@app.get("/{domain}/entity/{entity}/{id}")
async def read_users(domain: Domain, entity: Entity, id: Int):
    pass
```

considering `Entity` would be an Enum that could change following the selected domain.

For instance, if the domain is "architecture", Entity could be defined like :

```
class Entity(str, Enum):
    building = "building"
    floor = "floor"
```

but if the selected domain is "vehicle", the matching Entity would be :

```
class Entity(str, Enum):
    engine = "engine"
    wheels = "wheels"
```

More generally, I guess what I'm looking for is a way to make a path parameter validation dependent on another path parameter.

This way :

- `GET /architecture/entity/floor/1` is valid since, `floor` is a valid entity for domain `architecture`
- `GET /vehicle/entity/wheels/5` is valid since, `wheels` is a valid entity for domain `vehicle`
- `GET /architecture/entity/engine/1` is invalid since, `engine` is not a valid entity for domain `architecture`

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: What's your `Domain` model look like and how is it related to the `Entity` one?

Comment: A `Domain` could just be seen as a collection of `Entity` models. My goal is to be able to define domains and the entity models they contain with dynamic configuration like JSON.

Comment: It's difficult to get what you're saying without having an example of your data structures. `Domain` will contain a JSON field of `Entity` values? If yes, how are you gonna pass them in your `GET` requests? Also, both of your `Domain` and `Entity` are `enums` (and not sub classed from `Basemodels`) so I don't believe the Pydantic validators can work there.

Answer (score 10):

You can use closures. The following code does not use Enums for brevity :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


domains = {"architecture": ["building","floor"], "vehicle": ["engine","wheels"]}

def set_route(domain,entity):
    url = "/{}/entity/{}/{{id}}".format(domain,entity)
    @app.get(url)
    async def read_users(id: int):
        return(f"Users of the {domain} {entity} #{id}")

for domain, entities in domains.items():
    for entity in entities:
        set_route(domain,entity)
```

And it yields the desired API schema :
[image: API Schema]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if exactly what you want is possible, for sure you can write controller where you add pydantic validation, and handle exception if it throws validation error:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from enum import Enumfrom fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from typing import Union, Literal

class ArchitectureEntity(BaseModel):
    entity: Union[Literal['building'], Literal['floor']]

class VehicleEntity(BaseModel):
    entity: Union[Literal['wheels'], Literal['engine']]

@app.exception_handler(ValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: ValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(), "Error": "Entity not permitted"}),
    )

@app.get("/{domain}/entity/{entity}/{id}")
async def read_users(domain: Domain, entity: Entity, id: int):
    if domain == 'architecture':
        entity = ArchitectureEntity(entity=entity)
    elif domain == 'vehicle':
        entity = VehicleEntity(entity=entity)
    return {'architecture': entity}
```

However openapi docs will not show, that e.g architecture and engine are not allowed together.